# Using multiple animations for phaser 3 matter body

Tags: phaser-framework

How can I give a phaser 3 matter body an animation? Ideally I would like to switch between several animations.

So far I have only managed to give it a static image:

```
function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('human', 'assets/sprites/x2kship.png');
}

function create ()
{
    human = this.matter.add.sprite(300, 400, 'human');
}
```

I do have prepared files from an old project: atlas.png, atlas.json, animations.json. And it loads successfully:

```
this.load.atlas('sheet', 'data/atlas.png', 'data/atlas.json');
```

An example from the animations.json:

```
{
    "animations": [
        {
            "name": "human-walk",
            "frames": [
                "human1.png",
                "human2.png",
                "human3.png",
                "human4.png"
            ],
            "frameRate": 100
        },
        ...
```

The referenced files "human1.png" etc are found in the atlas.json:

```
    "human1.png": {
        "frame": { "x": 1137,"y": 1030, "w": 182, "h": 195 },
        "rotated": false,
        "trimmed": false,
        "spriteSourceSize": { "x": 0,"y": 0, "w": 182, "h": 195 },
        "sourceSize": { "w": 182, "h": 195 },
        "pivot": { "x": 0.5, "y": 0.5 }
    },
```

How can i stich these parts together to make the human do something like `human.animations.play('human-walk')`? And then maybe `human.animations.play('human-stand-still')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweeking the animations format I got it to work like this:

```
function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('human', 'assets/sprites/x2kship.png');    
    this.load.atlas('sheet', 'data/atlas.png', 'data/atlas.json');
}

function create ()
{
    var humanWalk = {
        key: 'human-walk',    
        frames: [
            {key: "sheet", frame: "human1.png"},
            {key: "sheet", frame: "human2.png"},
            {key: "sheet", frame: "human3.png"},
            {key: "sheet", frame: "human4.png"},
        ],
        frameRate: 6,

        repeat: -1
    };

    this.anims.create(humanWalk);

    human = this.matter.add.sprite(100, 100, 'human');
    human.anims.load('human-walk');
    human.anims.play('human-walk');
}
```